# I want to create an action on google assistant to control a smart lightbulb using a google home

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api, assistant

I want to create a new action that is able to understand my voice commands using google home in a foreign language and control my lights. Basically if i say a phrase in a foreign language it should understand to to turn the light on or off. Im starting from scratch and im lost.

Answer (score 0):

The [platform overview](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) is the best place to get started with information on how voice commands to the Google Assistant can be translated into commands for your device.

There are several [codelabs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs) to walk you through what's happening.